Making buffer around crossing point on lines intersection in QGIS
I have two line layers A and B. I need to create a point at the intersection of these layers (which is not a science using "Line intersection").
Is there a possibility to draw a new one on line B at the point where it intersects with line A layer following line B on one and the other side of the intersection for a certain distance (e.g. 100 meters)?
This is the initial state:

We run Line intersections, we get a common point (as below in the picture)

And now what I want to as a result - creating a new line layer that would automatically draw a line on LayerA, for example. 100 meters to the left and 100 meters to the right, from the intersection point, following LayerA.


A diagram, using your data and markup in Paint if necessary, would make this a great deal clearer. Please [Edit] the Question.

I will do it tomorrow in the morning...thx any way!

You can use either of the following expressions - Either as a Geometry Generator symbol layer (on Layer B) or by using the Geometry by Expression geoprocessing tool if you wish to create a new layer with the results (used also on Layer B).
The first expression works for situations where there is only one intersection point per feature on Layer B. The second expression works when there are multiple intersection points per feature on Layer B.
Single intersection point per feature
-- find the intersection of the line layers and assign it to a variable
with_variable('i',
    intersection(
        -- a small extension is applied to Layer A to ensure there is a true intersection with Layer B.
        -- the extension is applied at both ends so that the direction of the line does not need to be known
        aggregate('Layer A', 'collect', extend(@geometry, 1, 1)),
        @geometry
    ),
    
    -- get the distance of the intersection along Layer B's geometry
    with_variable('dist_along', 
        line_locate_point(@geometry, @i),

        -- generate the line that spans 100 m either side of the intersection
        line_substring(@geometry, @dist_along - 100, @dist_along + 100)
    )
)


Multiple intersection points per feature
⚠️ Be aware: due to the nature of Geometry Expressions, this will create a MultiLineString with duplicated geometries. You will need to run Multipart to Singleparts and then Delete Duplicate Geometries on the output to clean it up.
-- find the intersection of the line layers and assign it to a variable
with_variable('i',
    intersection(
        -- a small extension is applied to Layer A to ensure there is a true intersection with Layer B.
        -- the extension is applied at both ends so that the direction of the line does not need to be known
        aggregate('Layer A', 'collect', extend(@geometry, 1, 1)),
        @geometry
    ),
    
    -- collect the array of geometries into a MultiLineString
    collect_geometries(
        -- loop through each intersection point per Layer B feature
        array_foreach(
            -- convert the MultiPoint intersection geometry into an array of geometries 
            geometries_to_array(@i),
            
            -- find the distance of the intersection along the Layer B feature
            with_variable('dist_along', 
                line_locate_point(@geometry, @element),         
                
                -- generate a line that follows Layer B spanning 100 m either side of the intersection
                line_substring(@geometry, @dist_along - 100, @dist_along + 100)
                
            
            )
        )
    )
    
)


Note, when using either a Geometry Generator symbol layer or the  Geometry by Expression tool, don't forget to set the output geometry type to LineString / MultiLineString  or Line respectively.

It works perfectly in one combination LayerA cuts LayerB, but not at all in the opposite. I can't find a probably trivial error at all.

Are you able to share a small sample of data with various combinations?

How I share a data?

Maybe I have found the reason for the error... Layer A is a long line that is joined by several lines of Layer B.
When you need to mark a part on Layer B, it works, but if it's the other way around, it doesn't work.

It is therefore necessary to draw a new line approximately 100 meters to the left and 100 meters to the right of the intersection for each line of the 'TrainFinal' layer on the 'Road' layer.
The reverse works normally.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16J0Ytscn5LfoeXlWNk62sOibglEDxzDX/view?usp=drive_link

I hope now it will be available for all.

Please can you clarify which is Layer A and which is Layer B in your sample data, thanks.

on your picture LayerB is 'Cesta' and od that layer I need result (200 meters line), layerA is 'VlakeFinal'

Does my second expression solve your problem? It worked when I tested it on your data.

Dear Matt, I am not near a my data...I will try it tommorow morning and write something here...:)

Hi Matt, When I use Geometry by Expression I get this error -> Evaluation error: Cannot convert to geometry.

That's odd, it works for me on your sample data. Did you remember to change the name of the layer in the expression from Layer A to VlakeFinal?

Yes, I changed it myself. It works for me too on those test data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ksREwb0r_nKUDN0UDeyT_jZU61WW4tVe/view?pli=1

It's simple don't work... I share with all of you little more simpe data... I need you help @Matt  :)... maybe little hint, your expression work only if "cesta" have only one record...is that odd?
